# jquery click to expand down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want by clicking the image(represented by the cross box), a rectangle area will be expanded downward to display information(kind of toggle). How can I do that. Thanks.

when I click another image, I also want the first rectangle area will retract and the next will expand(i.e. only one rectangle area a time)

I want the similar effect here: themetrust.com/demos/reveal/#footloose , but what I really want is that the grey area to put under each row of the photos and probably expecting ajax and rails implementation.

[image: The mock up]

Comment: I want the similar effect here: http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/#footloose , but what I really want is that the grey area to put under each row of the photos and probably expecting ajax and rails implementation. thanks in advance.

Comment: Or like this: http://thoughtbot.com/ (clicking the images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given much information, but one strategy you could use is to associate each clickable `img` with a container that will show or hide:

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="img_src" data-target="#content1" />
    <img src="img_src" data-target="#content2" />
    <img src="imgs_src" data-target="#content3" />
</div>
<div id="contents">
    <div id="content1" class="active">Content1</div>
    <div id="content2">Content2</div>
    <div id="content3">Content3</div>
</div>
```

Then you could wire up an event handler for each image, retrieve the content and show it:

```
$("#images img").on("click", function () {
    var content = $(this).data("target");
    $("#contents .active").hide("slow", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(content).show("slow", function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
});
```

Also toggling an `active` class along the way.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/k8zCU/

You might want to check out the following documentation for more effects you could use:

- [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
- [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)
- [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)
- [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: @Thequestioner: Even though the markup will be slightly different and the effects might change a bit, the strategy shouldn't change much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var contentArray = ['content1', 'content2', 'content3'];

<div class="clickableSquare"></div>
<div class="clickableSquare"></div>
<div class="clickableSquare"></div>

<div id="contentBox">Content1</div>

$('.clickableSquare').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('#contentBox').slideUp('fast', function(){
        $('#contentBox').html(contentArray[index]);
        $('#contentBox').slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Iteracitve Click</title>
<style type="text/css">
.rect
{
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    float:left
}

#container
{
    position:relative;
    display: none
}

#toggler
{
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="rect1" class="rect">Rect 1</div>
<div id="rect2" class="rect">Rect 2</div>
<div id="rect3" class="rect">Rect 2</div>
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="toogler" style="width:200px; height:50px; border:1px solid #000;top:20px; "></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    function display(t) {
        var l = $(t).position().left;
        var w = $(t).width();
        var h = $(t).height();
        $('#container:hidden').animate({
            top: (h + 30) + 'px',
            left: (l + 40) + 'px'
        },50, function(){
            $('#container').show();
        });

    }
    $('.rect').click(function(){
        var that = this;
        if($('#container').is(':visible')) {
            $('#container').fadeOut(100, function(){ 
                display(that);
            });
        } else { 
            display(that);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```